# Como poner funciones async en addFields en mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

Muy buenas a todos, Es posible crear una funcion async en una funcion de addField?.

**Lista productos:**

```js
// Colección de productos
[
  {
    "_id": "producto-1",
    "nombre": "galleta de chocolate",
  },
  {
    "_id": "producto-2",
    "nombre": "Coca Cola",
  },
]
```

**Lista ingresos:**

```js
// Colección de ingresos
[
  {
    "_id": "5fd68725e66b1631244991b8",
    "proveedor":"5fd365c8b9f8651038af0bd6",
    "detalles": [
      {
        "producto_id":"producto-1",
        "cantidad": 20,
      },
      {
        "producto":"producto-2",
        "cantidad": 5,
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    "_id": "5fd68bdae66b1631244991ba",
    "proveedor": "5fd365c8b9f8651038af0bd6",
    "detalles": [
      {
        "producto_id":"producto-1",
        "cantidad": 3,
      },
      {
        "producto_id":"producto-2",
        "cantidad": 5,
      }
    ],
  },
]
```

Quiero sumar todas las cantidades de los detalles de ingreso de un producto, y mostrar el resultado en cada documento de la colección productos

**Resultado al que quiero llegar**

```js
//productos
[
  {
    "_id": "producto-1",
    "nombre": "galleta de chocolate",
    "cantidadTotal":23
  },
  {
    "_id": "producto-2",
    "nombre": "Coca Cola",
    "cantidadTotal":10
  },
]
```

Cómo lo estaba intentando hacer:

```js
export default {
  list: async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      const reg = await models.Producto.aggregate([
        {
          $addFields: {
            cantidadTotal: {
              function: {
                body:`function(args){
                  try {
                    return await models.Ingreso.aggregate([
                      { $unwind: "$detalles" },
                      { $match: { "detalles.producto_id":ObjectId(args) }},
                      { $group: {
                        _id: "$detalles.producto_id",
                        "stock": { $sum: "$detalles.stock" }
                        }
                      },
                    ]);
                  } catch (e) {........}
                }`,
                args: [ {$toString:"$_id"} ],
                lang: "js"
              }
            }
          }
        },     
      ]);
      res.status(200).json(reg);
    } catch (e) {......}
  },
}
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es la diferencia que habrá, según tú, al usar una función tipo `async`?

Comment: Lo que quiero ejecutar en esa funcion es una consulta de mongo, 
var reg=await model.Producto........

Comment: Pues eso no te funcionará, por dos simples razones: 1.- el proceso de agregación se ejecuta en el servidor de MongoDB, donde no existe la noción de Modelo o Esquema que defines en Mongoose. 2.- las funciones asíncronas siempre devuelven una Promesa, y el proceso de agregación que se ejecuta en Mongo no esperará por la resolución de dicha Promesa. Sería mejor que explicaras lo que quieres lograr, mostrando un ejemplo de dato y de la salida esperada. En cuanto a tu duda, no obtendrás el resultado esperado usando una función tipo `async`. Saludos

Comment: oh! muchas gracias por la aclaracion, voy aprendiendo soy nuevo en esto, lo que quieria intentar es hacer es listar todos los datos de una coleccion, y en cada documento agregarle una nueva columna, y en esa columna agregar un valor de otra consulta de otra colleccion

Comment: Como estás aprendiendo entonces te aclaro que: en MongoDB no hablamos ni de columna ni de tablas, hablamos de *campos*. Lo que deseas hacer se puede lograr mediante el método [`populate()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html), definiendo correctamente la referencia o referencias entre una colección y otra. O lo podrías lograr mediante un proceso de [`agregación`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) en caso que el método `populate` sea insuficiente. Saludos

Comment: Si agregas un [mcve] de lo que pretendes lograr, con gusto convierto mis comentarios en una respuesta y te muestro la forma de hacerlo. Puedes hacer clic en [edit] y agregar lo que creas suficiente y necesario: definición de ambos esquemas, la salida esperada y los campos involucrados. Saludos

Comment: muchas gracias por las correcciones, ya lo edite, espero se me entienda

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea realizar una consulta a una Base de Datos [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/), a una colección llamada *productos* para sumar la cantidad total de ingresos de cada producto que es reflejada en la colección *ingresos*.

**SOLUCIÓN**

**Resumen**

Puedes lograr el objetivo aplicando un proceso de agregación sobre la colección  de *productos*.

En total, el proceso de agregación consta de 5 etapas, como se muestra a continuación:

```js
db.productos.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "ingresos",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "detalles.producto_id",
      "as": "ingresos"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$ingresos"
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 1,
      "nombre": 1,
      "ingresos": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$ingresos.detalles",
          "as": "ingreso",
          "cond": {
            "$eq": [
              "$_id",
              "$$ingreso.producto_id"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$ingresos"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "nombre": {
        "$last": "$nombre"
      },
      "cantidadTotal": {
        "$sum": "$ingresos.cantidad"
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

---

**Explicación**

Podemos usar un proceso de agregación, esto permitiría hacer un [*lookup*](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) desde la colección de productos a la colección de ingresos.

Por ejemplo:

```js
db.productos.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "ingresos",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "detalles.producto_id",
      as: "ingresos"
    }
  }
]);
```

Esto creará un campo de tipo `Array` con el nombre *ingresos* en el resultado de la agragación, ahora podemos simplemente sumar los ingresos de cada producto usando los documentos que se proveen en dicho `Array`.

Podemos ver una implementación de este proceso de agregación temprana en el siguiente [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YL3d1xdZatp).

La salida se ve algo parecida a la siguiente:

```js
[
  {
    "_id": "aaaaaaaa",
    "ingresos": [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
        "detalles": [
          {
            "cantidad": 46,
            "producto_id": "aaaaaaaa"
          },
          {
            "cantidad": 35,
            "producto_id": "aaaaaaab"
          }
        ],
        "proveedor": ObjectId("5fe337331a4f5d08bae3da91")
      },
      // ... otros ingresos
    ],
    "nombre": "Trappistes Rochefort 8"
  },
  {
    "_id": "aaaaaaab",
    "ingresos": [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
        "detalles": [
          {
            "cantidad": 46,
            "producto_id": "aaaaaaaa"
          },
          {
            "cantidad": 35,
            "producto_id": "aaaaaaab"
          }
        ],
        "proveedor": ObjectId("5fe337331a4f5d08bae3da91")
      },
      // ... otros ingresos
    ],
    "nombre": "Old Rasputin Russian Imperial Stout"
  }
]
```

Ahora que ya tenemos los ingresos en un mismo documento podemos totalizar los ingresos de cada producto, pero si observamos bien, tenemos que los valores del campo ingresos, contiene detalles con diferentes productos ingresados, además incluyen campos que no necesitamos, como el proveedor y el valor `_id` del ingreso.

Vamos a sanitizar un poco los documentos, para ello primero debemos eliminar los datos no relevantes, y para lograrlo debemos dividir el `array` de ingresos en sus documentos internos. Haremos entonces una etapa [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) sobre el campo *ingresos*:

```
{ $unwind: "$ingresos" }
```

Nótese que para referirse a un campo del documento debemos usar el signo `$` antepuesto al nombre del campo.

Esto nos devuelve un resultado parecido al siguiente:

```js
[
  {
    "_id": "aaaaaaaa",
    "ingresos": {
      "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
      "detalles": [
        {
          "cantidad": 46,
          "producto_id": "aaaaaaaa"
        },
        {
          "cantidad": 35,
          "producto_id": "aaaaaaab"
        }
      ],
      "proveedor": ObjectId("5fe337331a4f5d08bae3da91")
    },
    "nombre": "Trappistes Rochefort 8"
  },
  {
    "_id": "aaaaaaaa",
    "ingresos": {
      "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
      "detalles": [
        {
          "cantidad": 28,
          "producto_id": "aaaaaaaa"
        },
        {
          "cantidad": 40,
          "producto_id": "aaaaaaab"
        }
      ],
      "proveedor": ObjectId("5fe337331a4f5d08bae3da92")
    },
    "nombre": "Trappistes Rochefort 8"
  },
  // ...
]
```

Podemos verlo en el siguiente [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YRAAvAWuT8S).

Ahora ya podemos deshacernos de los datos sobrantes y quedarnos solamente con los detalles del ingreso, para ello usaremos una etapa [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/index.html), la cual usaremos para sobre escribir el campo *ingresos* con el `array` de *detalles*:

```js
{
  "$project": {
    "_id": 1,
    "nombre": 1,
    "ingresos": "$ingresos.detalles"
  }
}
```

Esto produce el siguiente resultado:

```js
[
  {
    "_id": "aaaaaaaa",
    "ingresos": [
      {
        "cantidad": 46,
        "producto_id": "aaaaaaaa"
      },
      {
        "cantidad": 35,
        "producto_id": "aaaaaaab"
      }
    ],
    "nombre": "Trappistes Rochefort 8"
  },
  {
    "_id": "aaaaaaaa",
    "ingresos": [
      {
        "cantidad": 28,
        "producto_id": "aaaaaaaa"
      },
      {
        "cantidad": 40,
        "producto_id": "aaaaaaab"
      }
    ],
    "nombre": "Trappistes Rochefort 8"
  },
  // ...
]
```

Podemos verlo en acción en el siguiente [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/h9j2LC-VKE3)

Ahora que ya tenemos los datos algo más ajustados al resultado deseado, debemos eliminar los valores de *ingresos* que no se corresponden con el producto, para ello usaremos el operador [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/), que nos permitirá filtrar los elementos del `array` de ingresos descartando aquellos que no se correspondan con el producto.

```js
"$filter": {
  "input": "$ingresos.detalles",
  "as": "ingreso",
  "cond": {
    "$eq": [
      "$_id",
      "$$ingreso.producto_id"
    ]
  }
}
```

Como este operador no es una etapa de agregación, debemos usarlo dentro de una etapa, y dado que estamos haciendo una etapa `$project`, qué mejor que usarlo en dicha etapa, de esta forma, la etapa `$project` anterior quedaría reescrita así:

```js
{
  "$project": {
    "_id": 1,
    "nombre": 1,
    "ingresos": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$ingresos.detalles",
        "as": "ingreso",
        "cond": {
          "$eq": [
            "$_id",
            "$$ingreso.producto_id"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Esto produce ahora el siguiente resultado:

```js
[
  {
    "_id": "aaaaaaaa",
    "ingresos": [
      {
        "cantidad": 46,
        "producto_id": "aaaaaaaa"
      }
    ],
    "nombre": "Trappistes Rochefort 8"
  },
  {
    "_id": "aaaaaaaa",
    "ingresos": [
      {
        "cantidad": 28,
        "producto_id": "aaaaaaaa"
      }
    ],
    "nombre": "Trappistes Rochefort 8"
  },
  // ...
]
```

Como se observa, cada documento tiene un valor de ingresos que sólo se corresponde con el producto en cuestión.

Podemos ver el resultado del código anterior en el siguiente [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cgRKfDhucW7).

Ahora solo debemos totalizar, y para ello basta usar una etapa [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html), con la cual agruparemos todos los productos de un mismo tipo y sumaremos los ingresos de dicho producto. Sin embargo, como nuestro campo *ingresos* es de tipo `array`, podemos hacer primero una etapa `$unwind` para separar o romper dicho `array` en sus componentes.

Así la etapa `$group` la podemos escribir como:

```
// primero hacemos un $unwind
{
  "$unwind": "$ingresos"
},
{
  "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "nombre": {
      "$last": "$nombre"
    },
    "cantidadTotal": {
      "$sum": "$ingresos.cantidad"
    }
  }
}
```

En este caso estamos agrupando mediante el campo *_id*, además estamos añadiendo el valor del nombre del producto con el operador de acumulación [`$last`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/#grp._S_last), y estamos sumando las cantidades ingresadas mediante el operador de acumulación [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum), que sumará los valores del campo *cantidad*.

El resultado se verá parecido al siguiente:

```js
[
  {
    "_id": "aaaaaaab",
    "cantidadTotal": 119,
    "nombre": "Old Rasputin Russian Imperial Stout"
  },
  {
    "_id": "aaaaaaaa",
    "cantidadTotal": 153,
    "nombre": "Trappistes Rochefort 8"
  }
]
```

En total, el proceso de agregación consta de 5 etapas, como se muestra a continuación:

```js
db.productos.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "ingresos",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "detalles.producto_id",
      "as": "ingresos"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$ingresos"
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 1,
      "nombre": 1,
      "ingresos": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$ingresos.detalles",
          "as": "ingreso",
          "cond": {
            "$eq": [
              "$_id",
              "$$ingreso.producto_id"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$ingresos"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "nombre": {
        "$last": "$nombre"
      },
      "cantidadTotal": {
        "$sum": "$ingresos.cantidad"
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

En el siguiente [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4uRqEwmyw6e) puedes ver el resultado.

**Nota**

Existen otras formas de lograr el mismo resultado, tal vez realizando la consulta sobre la colección de *ingresos* y no sobre la colección de *productos*.